# code sequences with number and letter without 0,1,o & i

Tags: php, codeigniter, sequence, increment

i need to make code sequences

Eg. Start with A5B, next code will be A5C,A5D...
Until A59 then next A6A,A6B...A99 then next BAA,BAB,BAC

the sequences is A-Z  then continuous with 2-9

```
$x = $last; // Get Last Value From DB
$a = substr($x,0,1); // Get First String
$b = substr($x,1,1); // Get Middle String
$c = substr($x, -1); // Get Last String
if($c == 'Z'){
$x = $a.$b.'0';
}
elseif($c == '9'){
if ($b == 'Z'){
$x = $a.'0'.'A';
}
elseif($b == '9'){
$a++;
$x = $a.'A'.'A';
}
else{
$b++;
$x = $a.$b.'A';
}
}
else{
$x++;
}
```

its works but the problem is how to make the code sequences without using 0,1,o & i

please help
sorry for my english

Comment: If I understood right `$a = 'AAA'; echo ++$a; // AAB`

Comment: @splash58 how to make the code sequences without using 0,1,o & i ?

Comment: It will be without digits `$a = 'AAZ'; echo ++$a; // ABA`

Comment: @splash58 what do you mean ? i need the code sequences eg: AAA, if the last caracter reach Z it'll AA2 and  the code sequences is without 0,1,o & i
eg : AAZ and next is AA2 not AA1 because ill not using 1 *(0,1,o & i)

Comment: I misread your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not worried about performance, an easy fix is to just use a do-while loop to keep iterating until `$x` no longer contains any of the unwanted characters:

```
$x = $last; // Get Last Value From DB
do {
    $a = substr($x, 0, 1); // Get First String
    $b = substr($x, 1, 1); // Get Middle String
    $c = substr($x, -1); // Get Last String
    if ($c == 'Z') {
        $x = $a.$b.'0';
    } elseif ($c == '9') {
        if ($b == 'Z') {
            $x = $a.'0'.'A';
        } elseif ($b == '9') {
            $a++;
            $x = $a.'A'.'A';
        } else {
            $b++;
            $x = $a.$b.'A';
        }
    } else {
        $x++;
    }
} while (preg_match('/[01OI]/', $x));
```

Comment: i tested it, but why its keep load ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Does it not work for you?

Comment: the page keep loading if i use  do-while but its work when im use if-else

Comment: Then it's stuck in an infinite loop for some reason. See here for a working version: http://rextester.com/WRSX85807